# SQL Check constraint on set of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following table column. How do i ensure that `active` can only be set to true if and only if UserId is unique? note, orgId and UserId are composite key for many to many relations and userId can be a duplicate as well.

```
OrgId    int 
UserId   int
Active   bit
```

Example 1 - invalid because userid appears 2 times and active is set to true two times.

```
orgId userId active
1      2       1
2      2       1
```

Example: 2 valid.

```
orgId userId active
1      2       1
2      2       0
3      3       1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to ensure that at most one value of `userId` has `active = 1`.  You can do this with a filtered unique index:

```
create unique index idx_table_userId_active
    on table(userId)
    where active = 1;
```

Comment: @joe, considering accepting this answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This must be done by `trigger`. `Check` constraint rely on data on the same row - which is not your case.